# How to validate an array of custom objects with jsonschema in Python

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I have this primary schema for each one of my data points:

```
data_schema = {
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "name": {"type": "string"},
    "city": {"type": "string"},
    "distance": {"type": "number"},
    "extrovert": {"type": "boolean"},
    "favorite_temperature": {"type": "number"},
},
```

}

and then I expect a list of these called `data`. I want to validate them all, how can this be done using the `jsonschema` module?

This is my attempt which fails because it seems to not recognize my custom primary schema inside the array schema:

```
from jsonschema import validate
from time import time
from faker import Faker 
import numpy as np

Faker.seed(0)

fake = Faker() 
def create_data(x: int): 
    '''Create fake data'''

    # dictionary 
    data = [] 
    for i in range(0, x): 
        data_i = {}
        data_i['name']= fake.name() 
        data_i['city']= fake.city() 
        data_i['distance'] = np.random.randint(1,5)
        data_i['extrovert'] = fake.pybool()
        data_i['favorite_temperature'] = fake.pyfloat(left_digits=2,
                                                    right_digits=2)
        data.append(data_i)

    return data


data = create_data(3)

t0 = time()


data_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "city": {"type": "string"},
        "distance": {"type": "number"},
        "extrovert": {"type": "boolean"},
        "favorite_temperature": {"type": "number"},
    },
}

list_schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {"type": data_schema},
}

validated_data = validate(instance=data, schema=list_schema)

t1 = time()
duration = t1 - t0
print(f"Json_Schema validation lasted: {duration} sec")
```

This is the error I get:

```
jsonschema.exceptions.SchemaError: {'type': 'object', 'properties': {'name': {'type': 'string'}, 'city': {'type': 'string'}, 'closeness (1-5)': {'type': 'number'}, 'extrovert': {'type': 'boolean'}, 'favorite_temperature': {'type': 'number'}}} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: @Anentropic I ve added the error message in the questions

Comment: I think you have an extra level of `{"type": ...}` nesting... try just `"items": data_schema` in the list schema. See https://json-schema.org/learn/miscellaneous-examples.html#arrays-of-things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"items": {"type": data_schema}` should just be `"items": data_schema`.